# BizTalk | Logical ports are not visible on BizTalk admin console

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk orchestration which has a number of send ports. This orchestration is called by another orchestration in the same project.
When the project is compiled and deployed, the logical ports are not visible on BizTalk admin console with the following message:-

> The orchestration has no logical ports.

I have thoroughly checked that the ports in this orchestration are static and specify later.

BizTalk and VS Version 2010

This project was converted from BizTalk 2006 to BizTalk 2010.

Comment: This may be a bug - [see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2482225)

Comment: I used to change 1 shape (add one more line to it for example) and  rebuild the solution. This is indeed a bug I have encountered as well. Hopefully this is the same case with you, so you can resolve it.

Comment: Was there no errors when you deployed solution? Try to change your port type modifier to 'public'.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, That solved it. I added a space in one of the expression shape and then re-compiled and deployed the application. Ports were visible again.